# Panorama snapshot of entire apple map using swift?

Tags: swift, uikit, mkmapview, core-location

I am using a Map view in an iOS app that shows an apple map. Is it possible to take a snapshot of the entire map width so that it appears as a panorama view? I have seen MKMapSnapshotter using UIKit for taking snapshots of a given region but not the entire map. Thanks for your insight!

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by "snapshot of the entire map" and "as a panorama view"?

Comment: @oneshot when the apple map is zoomed out entirely, the whole map cannot be shown on one snapshot because it is too wide and tall. I am wondering if there is a way to capture the entirety of the map in image form

Comment: Ok, i might  be able to help you, but the question is still unclear to me. Do you mean that you are only able to take a screenshot up until a said zoom level, let's say you can take a screenshot of UK or Europe but not of the entire world, while you want that world screenshot (so, minimum zoom level)? Or that you're displaying the map in portrait mode, and when you take a screenshot at minimum zoom level (world) the map is cropped because of screen size, like this: https://i.imgur.com/pFFMHag.png? Two different issues, and two different solutions.

Comment: @oneshot the way I envision it working is that a single screenshot will contain the entire world map at minimum zoom level like this: https://geology.com/world/world-map.shtml

Comment: So you can actually take a screenshot at minimum zoom level like the one i posted in the image above, but you don't know how to capture the entire map, right?

Comment: @oneshot that is correct

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227970/discussion-between-qsaluan-and-oneshot).